# JSONException:no value for id

Tags: android-studio-2.3

i m using api created in laravel as a url to fetch data from database using xampp server in android studio 2.3.3

using the same wifi source.
checking internet permission
checking code

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
{
    try
    {
        id.setText(response.getString("id"));
        title.setText(response.getString("title"));
        body.setText(response.getString("body"));
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Expected result**: the value of id at id textview, value of title at title textview and body value at body textview.

**Actual result**: I get `jsonexception`; no value for id

Comment: Can you log the response or its contents? It appears id is not set n the response text.

Comment: how should i do this?

Comment: where does e.printstacktrace spit out the error? it might be the console in android studio.

Comment: yes it appears in console only

Comment: my json data is;      {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Est maiores nemo nostrum consequatur sed.",
            "body": "Nihil eum quos ex laboriosam. Sed et corporis officia voluptatibus et et deleniti voluptas. Placeat ea ut rerum et. Dicta ex non molestiae laboriosam nobis delectus."
        }
    ]
}

Comment: can i share my whole code with u

Comment: It appears its a array with single object. So you want to get jsonDATA[0].id

Comment: yes its an array but i m using api for a specific object.

Comment: api:http://192.168.43.98/firstcomposer/public/api/article/4"

Answer (score 0):

The image below talks about your data structure. Your error is that you are trying to access data in an array without accessing the element inside the array. 
[image: Your data's structure.]

Comment: then how can i access element inside the array??

Comment: log what a response object is

Comment: response object is same; { "data": [ { "id": 4, "title": "Est maiores nemo nostrum consequatur sed.", "body": "Nihil eum quos ex laboriosam. Sed et corporis officia voluptatibus et et deleniti voluptas. Placeat ea ut rerum et. Dicta ex non molestiae laboriosam nobis delectus." } ] }